# Visual studio 2005 debugging is very slow on windows7

Tags: debugging, windows-7, visual-studio-2005

When i debug apps on windows7 using VS 2005, it's very slow. just general slowness. works fine on xp.

running outside of the debugger is normal.  Even when i start apps outside the debugger then attach and debug it is normal.

im running VS 2005 in Vista compatibility mode.

Any idea what i can do to prevent slowness when debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem happens periodically and is related to the amount and location of breakpoints set in the debugger.  The problem can be worked around by attaching to the process after starting it.

For a complete solution, probably need vs2008.

Comment: thanks. that was helpful. this seems to be fixed now though. must have been fixed in a VS patch.